# In which case Spotify web API returns "added_at" as null for tracks ?

Tags: spotify

I am getting "added_at" as null for some tracks, wanted to know that is there a case in which Spotify returns null or this is an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The `added_at` value can be `null` in some cases for old playlists. From [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/#tablepress-93):

> Note that some very old playlists may return null in this field.